# why dynamic meta open graph tags not working?

Tags: html, next.js, meta-tags

I'm using Strapi as cms for my project and Nextjs, and I'm supposed to make meta open graph tags content dynamically, after it is deployed I try to copy and paste my website link to social media (FB, WhatsApp, etc) but the title and description not appear, this is my code:

```html
<meta
 property="og:title"
 content={(data.SEO.metaTitle) || ""}
/>
<meta
  property="og:description"
  content={(data.SEO.metaDescription) || ""}
/>
```

it only works when I hard-coded the content, any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research, the reason why the meta og tags are not displayed is because I'm still using client-side rendering (by using useState and useEffect), that's why the meta of tags won't appear. The solution is by using `getServerSideProps` so it will be rendered on server

Reference: https://www.techomoro.com/render-dynamic-title-and-meta-tags-in-a-next-js-app/

Comment: any idea how to do this with Flutter web?

Comment: @carrasc0 unfortunately i don't have any flutter experience

Comment: Is basically generates a one page web. same Index.html get refreshed with every new page, I have spent days and days and couldn't make it work.